# php coding being encripted

Tags: php, html, dreamweaver

Recently I was asked to take over the programming updating task of a php website. Interestingly, when I open the .php files by dreamweaver and Notepad++, I realized the codes are being encripted, just like md5.

Actually, how this be done, while not affecting their functions in Apache environment? And is there any way that we can resume the codes back to normal php and html presentations?

Thanks!

Comment: There are a lot of questions like this here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=decode+encoded+php+files It depends on the encoder, but they can always to reversed.

Comment: Can you show us some of the code please.

Comment: Show a piece of the code. I doubt it is "encrypted with md5", as that would mean data-loss. I'ts probably just obfuscated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably something along the lines of this:

```
eval(base64_decode('gobbledigoog...'));
```

In that case, just replace the `eval` by `echo`:

```
echo base64_decode('gobbledigoog...');
```

It's likely that this will result in more `eval('gobbledigoog')`, as the code may be encoded several times recursively. In that case, keep doing the above until you get real code.

Have fun.